# Implement similar module of pathlib in python 2

Tags: python

I have created a function where it will dynamically create a json file.
Currently i am using pathlib module which can be found in python 3 . However the server that i am deploying my script will only have python 2.7 and below.

The current approach im doing now work perfectly fine with pathlib module. When this was triggered in a higher environment, error im receiving is pathlib module not found. Hence i would go without using pathlib module when locating the base path to inject json content to publish_workbook.json

```
import json
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from pathlib import Path

def createJson():
    print("Creating Json File ....... ")
    ..
    ..
    event_dict = json.loads(_json)
    _jsonFile = json.dumps(event_dict, indent = 4, sort_keys=True)

    #Convert path to python 2.7 library orusing os.path
    base = Path('/home/reporting/job/')
    _saveFile = base / ('publish_workbook' + '.json')
    print("Saving json file on : " + str(_saveFile))
    _saveFile.write_text(_jsonFile)


createJson()
```

What is the best approach i can go with this ?

Comment: If your code must run in a Python2 environment, don't write code using features from Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it as strings.  It's actually fewer characters to type.  `Pathlib` has some cool concepts, but I'm not convinced it's a net win.  And, of course, for ***Python 2*** you don't have the `print` function.

```
base = '/home/reporting/job/'
_saveFile = base + 'publish_workbook.json'
print "Saving json file on : " + _saveFile
_saveFile.write_text(_jsonFile)
```

Comment: For one thing, `str.write_text` does not exist. You need to explicitly open the file and write to it.

Comment: Correct , i have made changes to string and i was able to run this. 
instead of doing write_text , i did `with open(_saveFile, 'w') as f` . this way i could write the json content

Answer (score 0):

Install [pathlib2](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/) on the server, which is a backported version of pathlib. It's no longer supported but then neither is Python 2.7.

You'll then only have to change the import line to

```
from pathlib2 import Path
```

Comment: Installing any additional module to server is not accepted as i have to use whatever the organization have install the module to server

Comment: @FaridArshad Sounds like it is time to remind the organisation that Python 2 is end of life and has been for quite a few years now. Unmaintained software can be a security risk.

Comment: @FaridArshad what a totally useless and asinine comment. lol do we run the company? no. even now though organizations is "transitioning" to p3 we are expected to have backwards comparability for lots of code for YEARS.